# How to find the specific score in the matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, search, alignment, bioinformatics

I am currently writing a program to find the local and global sequence alignment algorithm.
So, I need to find the specific score to be able to calculate my match and mismatch score.

```
-- A B C D T F
A  2 3 3 6 7 8
B  1 4 4 5 9 0
C  2 4 5 2 4 1
D  6 4 2 5 2 1
T  1 2 6 2 5 2
F  5 6 7 3 2 4
```

In this matrix, I have to find the score "B --> C" which is 4 or "C --> T" which is 4 or "B --> T" which is 9. I have just stuck here in my algorithm, Do you know any shortcut to find these scores from the matrix?
Thanks.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Using R, it is pretty simple: `myMatrix[ "B", "C" ]`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add language type. I am using Python!

Comment: what is this matrix? a numpy array? can you do ```type(>whatever your matrix is called>)```

Comment: Yes I used Numpy Array to create the matrix.

Comment: For the final result about my question. I have solved the problem by using lots of if function and define each element in the matrix (20X20 matrix) one by one. It works very well but so efficient if you'd like to work on 100X100 matrix and so on.